# why not encode(String) full size image via Base64 in android?

Tags: android, base64, decode, encode, android-image

When I want parse full image without resize but must be resize in requirement of code.
When I set

```
options.inSampleSize = 1;
```

Then decode of image show black. But I want full image 
that means

```
options.inSampleSize = 1;
```

and also

```
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

But I unable to make this.

My code below :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public String imageName, imagePath;
    public Context context;
    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    protected static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    public File dir;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "Test_Folder");
        if (dir.exists()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "folder already exist");
        } else {
            if (dir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "folder make now");
            }
        }

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        String randomName = new BigInteger(10, random).toString(4);
        imageName = "myImage" + "" + randomName + ".JPEG";
        File file = new File(dir, imageName);
        imagePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                options.inSampleSize = 16;
                options.inPurgeable = true;
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath,
                        options);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos);

                // bitmap object

                byte[] byteImage_photo = baos.toByteArray();

                // generate base64 string of image

                String imageRowData = Base64.encodeToString(byteImage_photo,
                        Base64.DEFAULT);

                Log.i(TAG, "::image::" + imageRowData);

            }
        }
    }

}
```

How to make sure full image encode without resize and decrease quality.
That means I want

```
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
```

and also

```
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

It is possible? please help me.

Comment: I want original image encode without resize and decrease quality of image via Base64 in android. Please help me